# How to replicate PS multiply layer mode

Tags: css, image, overlay, photoshop, rgba

Does anybody know of a good way to replicate Photoshop's multiply layer mode using either an image or CSS?

I'm working on a project that has thumbnails that get a color overlay when you hover over them, but the designer used a layer set to multiply and I can't figure out how to produce it on the web.

The best thing I've come up with is either using rgba or a transparent png, but even then it doesn't look right.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean, have you got pictures to help describe? Btw, I know an Andrew Philpott! How crazy!

Comment: Be sure to tell the designer that browser's aren't photoshop! The best way to avoid this sort of thing is for people designing for the web to have a good understanding of how it works. You imagine if we tried designing for print with <blink> tags?

Comment: http://doctype.com/ this is better place for this question.

Comment: Unfortunately I really didn't get much input with the designer. Also, they designed the thing in InDesign... CMYK.

Comment: There are some really good methods for image tinting using combinations of css3 and/or javascript here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/

Comment: In order to preserve the subtle gradients in complex line art you have to use your channels. This tutorial should help: http://www.tomrichmond.com/blog/2008/06/06/new-photoshop-line-art-trick/

Comment: Dude, did you try `z-index`? Example with `z-index` layer ordering: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDroid/VWMMu/

Comment: I know this is an easy way out but not the best probably, why not just create an image of the hover look directly from Photoshop. So in CSS you can just change the image from one to the other. If you have lot of images, you can use jQuery and call the other image.

Comment: I think the answers here are very good, but your approach depends on what browsers you are trying to accommodate. @Beejamin had some good advice to go back to the designer (might be worth going back again just to get the correct colors in RGB -- CMYK is great, but I don't think people print out their pages before viewing them) and Ljubisa's solution, although heavy handed, would probably get you some of the better cross browser results (i.e. have the thumbnail as normal and when you hover over, fade the multiplied version in over it).

Comment: I asked this question so long ago that I'm not even totally sure what I ended up doing. I think I went with rgba overlays and just got it as close as I could. It's cool to see that the SVG method is an option now (depending on what browsers you need to support).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are new CSS properties being introduced to do just this thing, they are `blend-mode` and `background-blend-mode`.

Currently, you won't be able to use them in any sort of production environment, as they are very very new, and currently only supported by Chrome Canary (experimental web browser) & Webkit Nightly.

These properties are set up to work nearly exactly the same as photoshop's blending modes, and allow for various different modes to be set as values for these properties such as `overlay`, `screen`, `lighten`, `color-dodge`, and of course `multiply`.. among others.

`blend-mode` would allow images (and possibly content? I haven't heard anything to suggest that at this point though.) layered on top of each other to have this blending effect applied.

`background-blend-mode` would be quite similar, but would be intended for background images (set using `background` or `background-image`) rather than actual image elements.

---

**EDIT:**
The next section is becoming a bit irrelevant as browser support is growing.. Check this chart to see which browsers have support for this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

---

If you've got the latest version of Chrome installed on your computer, you can actually see these styles in use by enabling some flags in your browser (just throw these into your address bar:)

```
chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features
chrome://flags/#enable-css-shaders

* note that the flags required for this might change at any time
```

Enable those bad boys and then check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqzJ5/
*(If the styles are properly enabled in your browser, the two images should be blended to make the scene look like it is underwater)*

While this may not be the most legitimate answer at the current moment due to the almost entirely nonexistent support for this feature, we can hope that modern browsers will adopt these properties in the near future, giving us a really nice and easy solution to this problem.

Some extra reading resources on blending modes and the css properties:

- http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/06/24/css-background-blend-modes-are-now-available-in-chrome-canary-and-webkit-nightly/
- http://demosthenes.info/blog/707/PhotoShop-In-The-Browser-Understanding-CSS-Blend-Modes
- http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/blendmodes/

Answer (score 18):

Simple with a bit of SVG:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="10 10 280 280">
    <filter id="multiply">
        <feBlend mode="multiply"/>
    </filter>
    <image id="kitten" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/300" />
</svg>
```

and some CSS:

```
#kitten:hover {
    filter:url(#multiply);
}
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uCQQ/381/

Comment: Any idea what browser support is like for this method?

Answer (score 17):

Just for the record, this guy is developing a library to do so. I just came into it while doing a research, haven't tried yet.

https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender

Answer (score 11):

It is possible with a 24.png - if you know the trick.

In illustrator you can export the graphic as a 24.png, but this never seems to work like multiply.

I've found away.

1. get your multiplied graphic on its own
2. place a solid black 100% box behind it, and select both graphics
3. in the transparency window select 'Make Mask' and then 'Invert Mask'
4. export as a 24.png file

works just like a multiply when z-index(ed) on top of a picture.

Comment: +1 Doesn't create the exact effect of a multiply, but gets very close to it! Thanks for this.

Comment: Would love to see an example of this on the web somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

No such ability is available. The only compositing options you get that are even close are:

- `lighter` compositing mode on an HTML5 `<canvas>` (which is a+b not a*b, and has about the opposite effect to multiply)
- `min` or `subtract` `Compositor` filters in IE only.

Neither are really practical.

In general you should not attempt to export Photoshop comps as layers, but render them down to a single opaque image. For rollovers you can make two images (one for normal state, one for hovered) and swap between them using the CSS `:hover` style to choose a different background image, or—better, as it requires no preloading and reduces HTTP requests—combine both images into one and use `background-image`/`background-position` to display the right part of that image in each state as a background image. (“CSS sprites”)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using sprites but that's not practical because the client is going to be publishing new entries and doesn't have access to Photoshop or anything like that.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the need to do exactly what the OP asked so I searched around. I found a great way to replicate the multiply effect by making a transparent PNG in Photoshop.

1. Create a new document with the same dimensions of your multiply
   layer.
2. Fill the document with black.
3. Add a vector mask (the icon to the left of layer "fx" at the bottom of the layers window).
4. `Alt/Option + click` on the mask itself.
5. Now copy and paste your multiply layer into the mask.
6. `Cmd/Ctrl + i` to invert the layer you just pasted.
7. Create a new layer below this layer and add the image behind the multiply overlay.
8. Everything should look pretty close to your desired result. If needed, you can adjust the `opacity` of the masked layer we created.
9. When it looks good just toggle the bottom layer's visibility and save the masked layer as a PNG et voila!

All credit goes to Sojeong from https://superuser.com/questions/381704/multiply-blending-mode-to-png

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:
http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photoshop-basics/remove-white-using-channels.10545.html

Using those instructions, I had great success watermarking a black-and-white image (ink drawing in my case, with blacks and greys on a solid white background) onto a dark background (wood in my case). There is hardly any difference with the real Multiply filter of Adobe.

I used the Photoshop instructions to remove the whites from my image, leaving only blacks and greys on a transparent background. Saving this to PNG and putting it on the wood in CSS/HTML still lookedmuch worse thanmultiply, but strongly reducing the brightness of the PNG solved it (the light greys stood out before, making it ugly).

In general I recommend you play around in photoshop, replicating the web situation: a semi-transparent (no special stuff) layer on top of a solid background. Tutorials such as the above may allow you to reproduce multiply or other fancy effects.

Comment: Excellent tutorial. Excellent workaround: just adjust the transparency of the image so "multiply layer" is no longer an issue. (And just excellent general PS knowledge.) Thank you so much for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you will have any luck. As far as I know, it isn't possible even if you tried to integrate some advanced JavaScript with it.

Comment: will probably just need two images with just a rollover state

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find any JavaScript solutions either. I ended up just using a CSS based overlay that's semi-transparent. It's not the exact same look, but it's the closest I can get since using image based rollovers won't really work in this case.